# Gradle idea plugin: add sourceDirs to specific module

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm trying add `sourceDirs` to a module that was added based on a source set named `model`. This module was added automatically by the [gradle-apt-plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin).

### What I've tried

I've been able to add the sourceSet to the main module:

```
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/apt/model')
        generatedSourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/apt/model')
        /* NOTE: adding it to generatedSourceDirs only doesn't work (seems to only mark it as generated) */
    }
}
```

All references and examples I could find are about changing the main/only module, but I'd like to configure a specific module instead.

In the Gradle docs I found a property `modules` on `IdeaProject`, so I tried this:

```
idea {
    project {

        println 'Module count: ' + modules.size

        modules.forEach { ideaModule ->

            def sourceSetName = ideaModule.name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('_') + 1)

            ideaModule.sourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/apt/' + sourceSetName)
            ideaModule.generatedSourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/apt/' + sourceSetName)
        }
    }
}
```

But there is only one module in this collection, even though I have multiple in my project.

### Question:

How can I configure specific modules?

Answer (score 1):

I got [help from Jetbrains support for this issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/1150096?page=1).

In summary, these are the current options:

- Turn off `Create separate module per source set` option in `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle settings`
- Include such generated sources folder into a main source set (this doesn't work for me - compiler then throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: endPosTable already set`)

There is also a [ticket added](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182577) to support the `annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory` property introduced in Gradle 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in specific module you can set:

```
sourceSets {
    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['build/generated/source/apt/model']
        }
    }
}
```

and needs to Turn off Create separate module per source set option in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle settings